# Cross browser request from Chrome Extension with OAuth.io

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth.io

I'm using OAuth.io to authenticate to Twitter from a Chrome Extension.

I've add the following to my `manifest.json`:

```
  "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["https://oauth.io/*"]
  },
```

I added the Gmail domain to the app in Oauth.io:

[image: oauth.io]

I get the popup and authorize, and then I get the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://oauth.io/request/twitter/%2Fme. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://mail.google.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'chrome-extension://chpcljbkkhhgnjpibemapkkioceikfmp' is therefore not allowed access.`

Any idea a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

I added this to the manifest.json and think that did it for now:

```
  "permissions": [
    "https://oauth.io/*"
  ],
```